# How to place label next to a checkbox control in Interop Word

Tags: c#, interop, office-interop, com-interop

How do you place 2 items side by side, for instance a checkbox and a label without creating new line in Interop Word?

This is the code I am using. It's making a new line because I put each item in a paragraph. How do you make it in one line?

```
 //CheckBox
 Word.Paragraph checkBoxparagraph = document.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
 Word.ContentControl checkbox = checkBoxparagraph.Range.ContentControls.Add(Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlCheckBox);
 checkBoxparagraph.Range.InsertParagraphBefore();

//Label
Word.Paragraph label = document.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
label.Range.Text = "Checkbox Label";
label.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

This is the output of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way, but I would wrap it in an inline shape. Sorry for not bothering to convert it to C#, but you should get the gist of it. If you like the solution you probably want to tinker with the styling, height and width of the text box

```
Sub CheckBoxLabel()
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim textBox As Shape
    Dim oRng As Range

    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oRng = oDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range

    oRng.Text = "My label"

    Set textBox = oDoc.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 40, 40, oRng.Characters(1))
    textBox.ConvertToInlineShape
    Set checkBox = textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlCheckBox)

End Sub
```